# How can I specify a namespace in method ODataHttpRouteCollectionExtensions.MapODataRoute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm getting the error: "Multiple types were found that match the controller named ..." and found the solution for the MapHttpRoute method.
Is it possible to pass an array of namespaces or something similar to MapODataRoute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instead consider implementing a new [IHttpControllerSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dispatcher.ihttpcontrollerselector%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). You can extend [DefaultHttpControllerSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dispatcher.defaulthttpcontrollerselector%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and override the SelectController method where you can resolve the ambiguous controller types and choose the one that you want.